# What can i use to automate video snapshots

Tags: video-processing

What command line util can i use to create a thumbnail preview of a video i made? I do not want a single thumb that windows make, i want a large jpg file that has 30 or less shots so i can preview the movie w/o running it.

I either need an app that can do a batch at once or a command line util so i can loop through a folder or w/e i need and feed it to the util. I was thinking of hacking up ffplay to do this, i dont know what i am getting myself into so is that recommended? (i used SDL many times, never its YUV settings nor with ffmpeg)

Comment: How is this programming related, aside from you saying you were thinking about writing something for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [MTN](http://moviethumbnail.sourceforge.net/). It can scan whole directories and create thumbnails for every video found.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to perform frame extraction, here's how I've done something similar

```
ffmpeg -i my_input_video.flv -y -an -sameq -f image2 -r 1 my_frame_%05d.jpg
```

- -i my_input_video.flv specifies the input file
- -y overwrite output files
- -an disables audio (we're transcoding a video to a series of jpegs, we don't need audio)
- -sameq - use same quality as source
- -f image2 sets the output format to image2 (an image sequence)
- The -r parameter is the frames per second, so the above command will produce one jpeg per second.

Once you have your collection of jpegs, you can use ImageMagick [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) command to  build a montage image.

Answer (score 2):

Use mplayer:

```
mplayer -vo jpeg -frames 1 your_file
```

Will extract the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

[Media Player Classic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/) can make a collection (it's called save as thumbnail; with matrix i.e. 4x4), but only from a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Potplayer can automatically generate the thumbnails for a batch of videos in folders or even in subfolders. It just takes a few clicks.

1. Add all the videos you want to get thumbnails from to the playlist (You can do this by go to menu "Open-Open Folder...")
2. Select all the videos in playlist and right click on them.
3. Select "Create Thumbnail Image(s)..." in pop-up menu.
4. Custom the output folder, number of Thumbnails, image size and other setting.
5. Click "OK".